# v-if on a VueJS component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

need a simple quick fix, I want to show a "DEVELOPMENT" tag on my VueJS footer when the NODE_ENV in .env is not "production". Please help.

```html
<template>
    <footer class="app-footer font-xs" v-if="process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'">
        <span>© 2018 <b>PT Test</b>. All Rights Reserved.</span>
        <span class="ml-auto">DEVELOPMENT</span>
    </footer>
    <footer v-else class="app-footer font-xs">
        <span>© 2018 <b>PT Test</b>. All Rights Reserved.</span>
    </footer>
</template>
```

My .env file

```js
NODE_ENV=local
TZ=Asia/Jakarta
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but you could certainly add more information to this question such as what result you get and what error messages appear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Vue template expressions are evaluated against the component context.

Add the condition to your component's `data` object

```js
data () {
  return {
    isProduction: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  }
}
```

and use

```html
v-if="!isProduction"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil, really appreciate your answer on such a newbie question :) Cheers!

Comment: In my opinion this is not correct approach. Better is create computed property or extends default Vue instance. Data should be for data like forms,...

Answer (score 4):

If you will need use check if production on multiple places you can do

`Vue.prototype.$isProductionEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`

Then in every component it will be available like this.$isProductionEnv so

`<div v-if="$isProductionEnv">Your contente</div>`